# Hiding specific images on initial page load for Jquery Image Slider

Tags: jquery, css

I have a Jquery image slider plugin called filter.js. See the demo [here](http://www.jscraft.net/demo/plugins/filters/). Now the issue is that when loading the page initially, all the images display. On initial load, I only want to display the first tab's/div's images, and when clicking on the next div/tab, its relative images will show. 
What I then added is setting the visibility of all images not belonging to the first tab/div, to hidden, and once the function is activated, I restore the hidden visibility to visible on the other tabs's/divs's images:

CSS:

```
.tancan{  /*Note: tancan is the class of the second div I initially want to hide*/
    visibility: hidden;
}​
```

JS:

```
$(function(){
        $('.filters.demo1').filters();
        $('.tancan').style.visibility = "visible";
    });​
```

My Problem: Doing it like this does not work, once I set the visibility to hidden, the

```
$('.tancan').style.visibility = "visible";
```

command does not work - Images stay hidden. I tried using display: none; and display: block but tha creates ugly transitions...
How can I only display the first tab's images on page load and not all of them?

PLEASE see my [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/YapAU/4/)

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems kind of hacky to me, but it works:

```
$('.filters.demo1').filters();
$('a[rel=koebana]').click();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/YapAU/21/

I took the last part out of the css, by the way.

Comment: Thank you, it works quite well, except for the initial glimps of the images that is suppose to be hidden, but it is acceptable...thank you

Comment: Interesting. It's not showing temporarily for me; I guess my javascript is just fast or something. What if you added a new class that had `display:none` to the `tancan` li's, then removed that class after "clicking" on the koebana link? Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/YapAU/22/

Comment: good thinking, but for some reason, it does not work on my site...clicking on anything does not work...only works in the fiddle...

Comment: Did you make the changes in the css file as well? I took the visibility:hidden part out of the css that you had in your original fiddle.

Comment: Ok sorry typo...between your code and David's code below I had an extra )}; which broke my code...

Comment: awesome stuff. thanks a lot, it works in all browsers. You were really helpful.

Comment: One more question though, why exactly the click function on a[rel=koebana] and not a[rel=tancan]?

Comment: Because you wanted to show the koebana images on load, right? You're basically simulating a click on one of the options, which hides the other options.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

JS:

```
$(function(){
    $('.filters.demo1').filters();
    $("#tancan").click(function(){             
    $(".tancan").css("visibility", "visible");
    });            
});
```

​

HTML:

```
<div id="content">
    <div class="galleryTitle">Photo Gallery</div>    
    <div class="filters demo1">
        <div class="filter">
            <a href="#" rel="koebana">Koebana Spray Tan</a>
            <a href="#" rel="tancan" id="tancan">Vertical Sunbed (TanCan)</a>
        </div>
etc..
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/YapAU/19/

Comment: thank you for your answer. Itworks, but just not in Firefox...It still displays all the imags at load...any suggestions?

Comment: Ok it works now, cleared my history in FF...Only reason why I prefer idor_brad's code above is because his transition of hiding the images initially and going to the next tab looks better than with yours...just a preference thing...but thank you very much, I voted you up...